# How to schedule local notifications that work for Android in 2022

Tags: android

First of all, **most of the answers here are more than 2 years old**. With so many API changes, none of them seem to work anymore.

When I say work, what I mean is that it should work when

- The App is closed (as in killed)
- The Phone is rebooted and the App has not been re-launched yet.

I am building a Calendar style App that sends local notifications and an exact time to serve as a reminder.

**I tried using the AlarmManager but it does not work when I close the App**. It somehow works if the notification is scheduled to come up 10 minutes later. But if it is more than that (like scheduled the next day), it ceases to work. However, the moment I open the App, lo and behold, all these past scheduled notifications come out!

Seriously Android needs to sort out their notifications!

Notifications are one od the MAIN REASONS to make a Mobile App. If not, websites/web apps work fine.

**One of the 2019 suggestions I found was to use the Foreground Service.** Seriously what? This is an overkill just to send notifications that occur once a week (or the case of my app)

Comment: You could use WorkManager -> https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#groovy. But for exact reminder you should use Alarm Manager with full-screen intent and tell users to disable battery saving for the app. Full-screen intent notification -> https://medium.com/android-news/full-screen-intent-notifications-android-85ea2f5b5dc1

Comment: Thank you @RageshRamesh. However your information is obsolete. It worked in 2019 however WorkManager will not fire anymore when the App is closed. I have tried disabling battery saving but it still ceases to work. I am not interested in Full Screen Intent Notifications. I just want a Simple Standard Notification

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code snippets about WorkManager mentioned by Ragesh Ramesh.

It can work in Pixel 6 for your use cases.

1. The App is closed (as in killed)
2. The Phone is rebooted and the App has not been re-launched yet.

According to the [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), WorkManager should meet your requirements

> Scheduled work is stored in an internally managed SQLite database and
> WorkManager takes care of ensuring that this work persists and is
> rescheduled across device reboots

Additional [notes](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006) , WorkManager's limitation

> For this reason, even if all the constraints set on a WorkRequest are
> satisfied, your Work can still be run with some additional delay.

If you still have trouble, please look for [google-labs(WorkManager)](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-workmanager/issues/69), and my opinion might relate to the OEM issue.

```
class OneTimeScheduleWorker(
    val context: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android_cupcake)
            .setContentTitle("Scheduled notification")
            .setContentText("Hello from one-time worker!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
            notify(Random.nextInt(), builder.build())
        }
        
        return Result.retry()
    }

}

fun schedulePeriodicNotifications() {

    val periodicWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<OneTimeScheduleWorker>(
        15, TimeUnit.MINUTES
    ).addTag("WORK_TAG").build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(this)
        .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            "WORK_NAME",
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            periodicWork
        )
}
```

and add the below codes as [build-notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) if need

```
   // You must create the notification channel before posting any notifications on Android 8.0 and higher,
    // you should execute this code as soon as your app starts
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = getString(R.string.appwidget_text)
        val descriptionText = getString(R.string.looper_event)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`WorkManager` isn't sufficient for accurately scheduling a reminder.

Register [`Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM) in `AndroidManifext.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM"
    android:minSdkVersion="33"/>
```