# Android schedule local notification alarms with precision in 2023

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to schedule precise local notifications in Android as of 2023? In my case +/-60 seconds around the scheduled time would be good enough to count as precise. I implemented AlarmManager and can schedule a local notification in the future at some elapsed time, but my experience is the same as this person [How to schedule local notifications that work for Android in 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090389/how-to-schedule-local-notifications-that-work-for-android-in-2022) where notifications with a longer period of time just don't show up until I open the app. Their question doesn't seem to be answered satisfactorily, anyway both AlarmManager and WorkManager don't seem to be a good solution according to [How schedule local notifications Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106006/how-schedule-local-notifications-android?rq=3). Is this possible and if so, how?

(if it matters my application is a reminder app where the app needs to send a local notification to the user if a sensor has no events during the given time period)

Edit: adding the code.
MainActivity.kt
UI has two buttons, one to request permission for notifications, one to schedule a notification. The function showDelayedNotification is where the AlarmManager is set up. I've been testing on a Samsung A14.

```
package com.example.localnotificationstest

import...

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val notify = NotificationSetup(applicationContext)
        notify.createNotificationChannel()

        setContent {
            LocalNotificationsTestTheme {
                val context = LocalContext.current

                var hasNotificationPermission by remember {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                        mutableStateOf(
                            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                context,
                                Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                            ) ==
                                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        )
                    } else mutableStateOf(true)
                }
                val permissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                    contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                    onResult = {isGranted -> hasNotificationPermission = isGranted})

                MainUI(context, permissionLauncher, hasNotificationPermission)

            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainUI(context: Context, perm: ActivityResultLauncher<String>, hasPermission: Boolean) {
    val notificationHelper = NotificationHelper(context)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                perm.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Request Permission")
        }
        Button(onClick = {
            if (hasPermission) {
                //showNotification(context)
                showDelayedNotification(context)
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Show Notification")
        }
    }
}

fun showNotification(context: Context) {
    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationHelper.CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_background_search)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setContentTitle("Snuff this notification")
        .setContentText("Hello this is your local notification")

    notificationManager.notify(NotificationHelper.NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
}

class NotificationBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (context != null) {
                showNotification(context)
        }
    }
}

fun showDelayedNotification(context: Context) {
    val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val notificationIntent = Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

    val broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        100,
        notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000L, broadcast)
}

class NotificationSetup(private val context: Context) {
    fun createNotificationChannel() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = "NotificationTest"
            val descriptionText = "Used for testing notification stuff"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                NotificationHelper.CHANNEL_ID,
                name, importance
            ).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }

            val notificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}

class NotificationHelper(private val context: Context) {
    companion object {
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "counter_channel"
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
    }
}
```

AndroidManifext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.localnotificationstest"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LocalNotificationsTest"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <receiver
            android:name=".NotificationBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.LocalNotificationsTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: WorkManager is not how you'd schedule a notification.  JobScheduler is more appropriate.  Which is really just a convenience layer on top of AlarmManager.

Comment: But to tell you what you did wrong with AlarmManager (which is totally enough to do this), we'd need to see your code.  Also remember that AlarmManager does not persist across device reboots, when the device restarts you'd need to schedule a new alarm.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan! Good to know I'm headed in the right direction at least. I feel kinda silly but I may have accidently solved the problem. was working on something else and it started working, I think I narrowed it down to one of the app settings - battery setting needs to be 'Unrestricted' not 'Optimized'. I thought I had double checked all the power setting like this, but I must have somehow missed that one. With it Unrestricted it seemed to work fine. With Optimized it gave the symptoms above. But either way, does the code look ok?

Comment: Try setExactAndAllowWhileIdle, that may fix the low power mode issue

Comment: @GabeSechan that worked, I tested it with delays of a few hours and they still come even with the battery settings at optimized. Thanks for your help. I'm new here, what happens now? do you post that as an answer and then I mark it as accepted?